# How to copy/cut file(s) from one directory and sub directory and paste into another

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have directory which contains sub-directories and files. For example

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\test"
```

and I want to copy/cut files and paste in another directory such as

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\new_test"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: [shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) is the most portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find everything you need: http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Copying whole directory:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

Deleting whole directory:

```
shutil.rmtree(path[, ignore_errors[, onerror]])
```

Moving directory:

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Example code, that does what you want:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("C:\Users\Desktop\test", "C:\Users\Desktop\new_test")
```

Comment: Posluszny:Thank you. But I want to copy/cut and paste selected files only.